# Getting the ActiveMQ version from the jar

Tags: java, activemq-classic

Is there an option to find the Apache ActiveMQ version from the ActiveMQ jar?
Does it log the inforamtion or is there a file present in the jar?

Comment: You may look into META-INF dir inside jar.

Answer (score 3):

From a Java Client you can get this information by calling

`org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionMetaData.getProviderVersion()`

Answer (score 2):

I found this in activemq-all-5.7.0.jar's manifest file

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
Implementation-Title: ActiveMQ :: All JAR bundle
**Implementation-Version: 5.7.0**
Implementation-Vendor-Id: org.apache.activemq
Built-By: dejanb
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_33
Specification-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
Specification-Title: ActiveMQ :: All JAR bundle
Created-By: Apache Maven
**Specification-Version: 5.7.0**
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver

Comment: The following are the contents of MANIFEST.MF in our jar.Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: gtully
Build-Jdk: 1.5.0_15
Created-By: Apache Maven
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver